# A word opposite of friend? Not "enemy"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms, antonyms

I don't speak English natively, but I wanted to know if there is a word that can describe someone you dislike/hate without it sounding so harsh like the word enemy or rival.

Not an insult, either.
For example:

> You call someone you love *"partner"*.
> Someone you like *"friend"*.
> Someone you know *"acquaintance"*.
> And someone you don't like____?

Comment: I don't think there is a single word: *And someone you don't like is **someone that you, etc avoid***

Comment: @Greybeard oh thank you! I was searching for like a one word, sadly it doesnt exist. I might try using "avoids" or a similar word. Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you looked in a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/enemy)? It's hard to judge what words you consider harsh; if you hate someone, any way of expressing it is going to be a bit harsh, but "rival" doesn't sound too harsh to me ("friendly rivalry" is a thing).

Comment: Informal: *frenemy* — a person with whom one is friendly despite a fundamental dislike or rivalry.

Comment: There's also words like "jerk", twit", "imbecile" to express your disdain for them.

Comment: There is no single word. It's just a person you dislike.

Comment: You single out the main reason you dislike them and call them that: an idiot, a jerk, a cheater, a racist… etc.

Comment: Possibly "antagonist" if they annoy you.

Answer (score 3):

The only English expression I can think of is a French loan word (actually a phrase), but it is given in standard British and US dictionaries:

> [Bête noire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bete%20noire)

Merriam Webster defines it as “a person or thing strongly detested or avoided” and, like my British Chambers, gives:

> Bugbear

as an equivalent. However this was originally applied to things rather than people, and still is, in my opinion, less used with people than *bête noire*.

Although the former is not the sort of word used by the masses, and the latter feels a little dated, both contain the meaning of dislike, without the extreme of *enemy*.

Comment: I see on refreshing my browser after finishing this answer (supper called) that @ermanen posted an answer which included Bete noire, but appeared to dismiss it as a loan word. However I shall let my answer stand because although this is originally a loan word, it is now almost as English as Court Martial.

Answer (score 0):

Will "[dislike](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dislike)" do?

> to not like; to find someone or something unpleasant, difficult, etc.:
> **something that you do not like**

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like them: enemy.

If you just don't know them: stranger.

Comment: Or someone you know, but are indifferent to.  In this sense, I suppose that there are symbiotic sorts of relationships as well, like a catalyst, which isn't directly involved in a chemical reaction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This sounds somewhat like a translation from some other language where stranger has more extensive meanings than in English.

Comment: "enemy" IS far stronger that disliking someone!